# Automatically check whether all symbols are listed in the nomenclature

Tags: automation, nomenclature

Sometimes, I write long documents with a huge amount of abbreviations and mathematical symbols. Up to now, I used to check manually if all of them were declared in the nomenclature, which is a very tedious.

Is there a way to automatically check that all of them were declared in the nomenclature once and only once?

(If that matters, know that I am using [nomencl package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) , [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) and [TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/).)

Comment: Don't add off topic tags. Those you inserted are not relevant for the question.

Comment: What package are you using to create your nomenclature?

Comment: I am using the  [nomencl package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl)

Comment: If you are correctly using the features of `nomencl`, then all you index with `\nomenclature` will appear.

Comment: @egreg I agree, but what if I forget to index a given variable? is there a way to detect it automatically, and display it as a `warning` in the compilation?

Comment: @user2536125 TeX is not clairvoyant; what do you mean by “a given variable”? If it's not in some list, how can anybody check if you have indexed it?

Comment: @egreg well, if Tex checks every variable declared in a math environment, or any abbreviation (which is a mostly a word not found in the dictionary), this seems to be possible. I might be mistaking, though

Comment: As for abbreviations consist of capital letters, a single regular expression `[A-Z]{2,}` is enough. But what do you mean by *variable declared in math*?

Comment: @Symbol1, by variables declared in math, I meant everything inside `math`environment. can you please explain what the expression [A-Z]{2,}` means?

Comment: Perhaps [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) helps. `[A-Z]{2,}` means *at least two consecutive capital letters*.